# Can't pass value during the contract deployment in Remix

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, remix

I am deploying a contract with the following code using `Remix`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Lottery {
    address public manager;
    address[] public players;
    
    function Lottery() public {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value > .01 ether);

        players.push(msg.sender);
    }
}
```

Without entering any value before the deployment, it is deployed successfully but if I specify any value it fails with the following err: `false Transaction mined but the execution failed`.

[This is the params I trying to deploy a contract with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z9wI.png)

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this error because the `Lottery()` constructor function is not payable. When you enter a value before deployment, it sends that value of Wei to `Lottery()`, but `Lottery()` does not have the `payable` keyword and so it fails.

To fix this I would deploy the contract without any value argument, then create a new function so the owner can set the value of the lottery prize. I would also try writing it in a newer version of Solidity.